# Adding a custom box to the navigation bar in Sphinx ReadTheDocs Theme

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I need to import a custom box into the navigation bar. Basically, something like the S*upport Read the Docs!* box on the website (https://sphinx-rtd-theme.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Where is "Support Read the Docs!"? I don't see it. If you want to inject your own advertisement, actually you need to override the template, https://github.com/obfuscar/docs/blob/master/_templates/layout.html#L3

Comment: The "Support Read the Docs" is on the left hand side, within the navigation bar, it's a green box.

Comment: That’s the advertisement I said. Everyone sees a different one and you can embed your own like I revealed.

Comment: Check the repo for RTD to see how they do it.